# Nested pointer instead of inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have some source code in C++, which I need to understand and extend / modify. According to the documentation some classes are planned as base and derived classes to implement an inheritance mechanism. 
When I look into source code, the derived class is not derived from the base class but it has a pointer to the base class as a private member.
As far as I understand, inheritance is an is-a relationship and the implementation is just wrong. But I am fairly inexperienced with object oriented concepts and I might be missing something. Is there a reasonable explanation / scenario why you would implement inheritance using a has-a relationship?

Comment: There are good reasons to implement has-a relationship with composition. However that is not inheritance any more. For it to be inheritance you need to inherit something, with composition you don't inherit anything.

Comment: Unless the `is-a` relationship is really the weakest possible relationship between classes, there shouldn't be a reason to use inheritance. Perhaps the legacy classes you have were revised before you got them?

Comment: So, just as I thought: It's not inheritance anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source code and documentation contradict each other (although each one might make some sense on its own). The is-a relationship in (runtime) C++ is through inheritance alone (see the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

In this case, the relationship is has-a, or implemented-in-terms-of. Making the composition through pointers might make sense in a few cases:

- Some variation of (possibly static) implementation hiding (see the [PImpl Idiom](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pimpl+idiom))
- The composed pointer member might be itself used for polymorphism, possibly even changing dynamically. This is used, e.g., in the [State Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) and [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reasonable explanation / scenario why you would implement
>   inheritance using a has-a relationship?

This implementation is not inheritance. This is pimpl idiom, you can read more details here : http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom